# Videos requires to install plugins to play files of the following types: • MPEG-4 AAC decoder • H.264 (High Profile) decoder

Tags: source

i am unable to perform the task though i followed the instruction. how to handel Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras?

Comment: If you use "Movie player" (the default app) it will prompt you to install missing codecs. In case the answers below are too difficult ;-)

Comment: For me the system wasn't able to install required codecs for some reason, but I installed VLC media player and it played the audio right away.

Answer (score 2):

Unable to locate package ubuntu-restricted-extras?
Make sure that all Ubuntu repositories are enabled.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo add-apt-repository main
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo add-apt-repository restricted
```

Now install the packages :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras
```

Note :

Maybe the `ttf-mscorefonts-installer` lets the installation process hang, because the license agreement is hidden in the background. So make sure to accept the Microsoft license agreement.

Answer (score 0):

Go to software sources and enable restricted and multiverse repositories, then update and install ubuntu-restricted-extras package

Hope if helps